# detect click, check attribute value and text inside, and display element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, userscripts

I need to detect click of an element(.menuitem), check the text it contains.
And then based on the attribute(is-checked), hide or show other elements.
I need this only when clicking that other button.

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="menuitem" is-checked="true">
    <div class="ytp-menuitem-label">Button 1</div></div>
  <div class="menuitem" is-checked="false">
    <div class="ytp-menuitem-label">Button 2</div></div>
</div>
<div class="element">some content</div>
<div class="element">some more content</div>

$('.menuitem').click(function () {
if ($('.menuitem').text().trim() === "Button 2"){
if ($('[is-checked="true"]'))
  $('.element').css('display', 'block');
if ($('[is-checked="false"]'))
  $('.element').css('display', 'none'); }
});
```

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ytepuo6o/), of what I have:

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ytepuo6o/1/)

Comment: @guradio you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic posting it

Comment: OK, now I feel silly.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.menuitem').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text().trim())
  if ($(this).text().trim() === "Button 2") {
    if ($(this).attr('is-checked') == 'true') {
      $('.element').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $('.element').css('display', 'none');
    }





  }
});
```

```css
.items {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menuitem {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="menuitem" is-checked="true">
    <div class="ytp-menuitem-label">Button 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuitem" is-checked="false">
    <div class="ytp-menuitem-label">Button 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="element">some content</div>
<div class="element">some more content</div>
<div class="element">even more content</div>
```

1. Use `$(this).attr('is-checked')` to get the value
2. Also use `$(this).text().trim()` to get the text of clicked element

Comment: Thankyou. This helped me.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I can't get it to work as a userscript. I would like to add this to the head of a website.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it a tad wrong, your if statement isn't actually looking at the element which was clicked. Try something along these lines:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function () {
    // $(this) is a reference to  the element which was clicked
    if ($(this).attr('is-checked') == "true") 
        $('.element').css('display', 'block');
    if ($(this).attr('is-checked') == "false")
        $('.element').css('display', 'none');
});
```